# Remove a row in pandas using Chain rule

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have below code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, None, 1],
                   "B":[7, 2, 54, 3, None],
                   "C":[20, 16, 11, 3, 8],
                   "D":[14, 3, None, 2, 6]})
df
df[df['A'].notna()]
```

Last line remove entire row of `df` for which `A` is `None`.

However to improve readability, I was achieve this final `dataframe` is one line where I created `df`, using chain rule.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal the expected output is that of `df[df['A'].notna()]`, but in a pipeline ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a function/lambda:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, None, 1],
                    "B":[7, 2, 54, 3, None],
                    "C":[20, 16, 11, 3, 8],
                    "D":[14, 3, None, 2, 6]})
        .loc[lambda d: d['A'].notna()]
     )
```

output:

```
      A     B   C     D
0  12.0   7.0  20  14.0
1   4.0   2.0  16   3.0
2   5.0  54.0  11   NaN
4   1.0   NaN   8   6.0
```

Documentation:

> Allowed inputs are:
>
> [...]
>
> **A callable function with one argument** (the calling Series or
> DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the
> above)